# Parse enum when string is lowered

Tags: c#, .net, enums, .net-4.5

I have a pretty fun problem, which I am not sure you can even solve using this approach.

I have some string, which is all lowercase. Let's just call it **businesslaw**. Now, I have an enum type, where the value is **BusinessLaw**.

What I want to do, is to convert the businesslaw string, into a BusinessLaw enum type.

Normally I would approach it by doing this:

```
return (EnumType) (Enum.Parse(typeof (EnumType), value));
```

However, that is not possible when there is some case difference.

How would you solve this issue? Or is it by nature, unsolveable?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [the overload of `Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx) with a final parameter to indicate case-sensitivity:

```
return (EnumType) (Enum.Parse(typeof (EnumType), value, true));
```

There's a similar [`TryParse` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317.aspx).

However, bear in mind that there *could* be multiple enum values with the same name other than case:

```
public enum Awkward
{
    FOO,
    foo,
    Foo,
    fOO
}
```

You should probably avoid having such enum values if possible :)

Comment: And there we have the perfect answer. Thanks a lot for saving my day! Luckily the could scenario is not there :-)

Comment: A note for anyone copying this: the `ignoreCase` argument must be `true` to ignore case, not `false`.